# Attach dynamically added values to jsf backing bean property

Tags: jsf

I have a jsf page which has a selection popup. User can select the members from this popup and click on 'Add'. After that, the selected members will be displayed on main page. This popuup is opened and closed through javascript and page doesn't refresh in this process.

Now the question is **how can I take these selected members up-to backing bean**? can I attach them to backing bean property directly?

Comment: Is it a jsf2 or jsf1.x ?

Comment: Havent touched jsf 1 for years... cant you submit a hidden form? Or send with servlet using jquery and grab the bean from session... ?